# Is there a way to enable integrated graphics on a MacOS Virtualbox guest? MacBook Pro host

Tags: macos, mojave, performance, virtualization, virtualbox

I have been trying to run OS X El Capitan in Virtual Box. The host is a MacBook Pro running macOS Monterey (12.2.1):

(cannot post images  for some reason, but this is the **About My Mac** info on my host system)

```
macOS Monterey
Version 12.2.1

MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015)
Processor      2.2 GHz Quad-Core Intel Core i7
Memory         16 GB 1600 MHz DDR3
Startup Disk   Macintosh HD
Graphics       Intel Iris Pro 1536 MB
Serial Number  C02PXA4RG8WN
```

The installation has been successful, and El Capitan seems to work correctly. However, the graphics are rather slow and when I check the **About My Mac** information on the guest, it seems that the system is not detecting the integrated graphics:

```
OS X El Capitan
Version 10.11.6

MacBook Pro
Processor      2.19 GHz Unknown
Memory         4 GB 1600 MHz DRAM
Startup Disk   Macintosh HD
Graphics       Display 3 MB
Serial Number  Hardware:
```

The guest system **About My Mac** information generally does not seem right... I would rather it showed the same hardware as my host system.

**Is there a way to make the guest use the Intel Iris Pro integrated graphics?** If so, how? It seems that the drivers are normally installed automatically, which has obviously not happened on the virtual machine.

Comment: It's always the same using a VM. They cannot address the hardware directly, they must use an interpreter. [I don't know the technical reason for this so I'll leave the actual answer to someone who does know] This, though, is part of the 'you get what you pay for' aspect of VMs. VB is the slowest, Parallels the fastest. As far as I'm aware, Fusion is somewhere in between.

Comment: Please don't cross-post to multiple SE sites. Pick one & stick to it, or flag for migration. 
[Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/) - https://superuser.com/questions/1709812/is-there-a-way-to-enable-integrated-graphics-on-a-macos-virtualbox-guest-macboo